# No of `columns` in pandas DataFrame limited to 1024

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I have an excel sheet with 15 rows and 1445 columns(24*60 +5 columns). The data contained in 1440 columns (24*60) columns are time series data.

I have the following python code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

a=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print('a.size {}'.format(len(a.axes[0])))
print('a.size {}'.format(len(a.axes[1])))
for x in a.iterrows():
    x[1][4:].plot(label=str(x[1][0])+str(x[1][1])+str(x[1][2])+str(x[1][3]))
```

I get the following output.

```
a.size 15
a.size 1024
```

For some reason the number of columns are getting truncated to 1024. Is that a limitation of the machine that I am running on? or is it something else? How do I get around this limitation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I made a csv with a lot of columns and got this: `print('chart1.size {}'.format(len(chart1.axes[1])))`  `chart1.size 1619`. I'm on a new-ish 64 bit laptop...

Comment: @snd - strange.something on my system seems to be limiting it. does lots of column mean 1619 or is it more than that?

Comment: Oh yeah, by lots I mean 1619 columns. Just made it an even 2000, outputs this: `chart1.size 2000`.

Answer (score 0):

Some Spreadsheet viewers may have a limit on the number of columns to view. For example, I have a CSV file with 4097 columns that when viewed with LibreOffice, it is 1024 columns only.

However, the CSV file usually has all the columns. To make sure the exported CSV file has proper column count, open it in any text editor. If there is mismatch, then there is a problem with the code that exported the CSV.